# Unity Triggering a Method Once Only at the Beginning of the Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, triggers, dialog

I'd like to show dialogue text at the beginning of my unity game as an introduction narration.

I have a method which holds the dialogue text then calls another method which writes the text out to a UI text box. This works fine if I have a button. However, I want it to happen when the scene loads for the first time, but because I'm leaving the scene and coming back within the same game, I don't want to welcome the player back to the scene they just left everytime they reenter.

button => method => another method writes to UI textbox

How could I do this without a button at the beginning?

Code

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dialogue dialogue; // array of strings past in

    public void Start()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue); //find the dialogue manager and plays the startdialogue method I suppose, should do this once the script is loaded because it is the start method
    }
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Queue<string> sentences;
    public Text dialogueText;
    
    void Start() // dialogue manager turns sentences into queue for the sentence input into dialogue manager
    {
        sentences = new Queue<string>();
    }



    public void StartDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
    {
        //sentences.Clear(); // clears sentences

        foreach (string sentence in dialogue.sentences) //each "sentence in the dialogue goes through and enters the queue one by one
        {
            sentences.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNextSentence(); //display next sentence method is called once all sentences are in the queue
    }

    public void DisplayNextSentence()
    {
        if(sentences.Count == 0) //once there are no sentences left (queue or otherwise?) the end dialogue method is called
        {
            EndDialogue(); //prints out that the queue has ended... ok 
            return; // this return is what really ends the dialogue
        }

        string sentence = sentences.Dequeue(); //new sentence for sentences that are being dequeued...
        dialogueText.text = sentence; //dialogue text is supposed to be the same as the sentence that was just dequeued and this should print out to whatever text was assigned to the variable dialogue text
    }
```

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html). Create a new script called `DialogueTrigger`. Then attach it to an empty `GameObject` in the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Array of strings past in
    public Dialogue dialogue;

    public void Start()
    {
        // Keeps the gameobject alive on scene changes
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // Find the dialogue manager and plays the start dialogue
        FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().StartDialogue(dialogue);
    }
}
```